# Some generator object clarification

Tags: python-3.x, string

I was trying to solve a coding problem and found this interesting solution. Since I clearly have no idea what is going on, please help.
The question link:
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/58/A

```
s=iter(input());print('NYOE S'[all(c in s for c in 'hello')::2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this (imho obfuscated) code, you should divide it.

`'NYOE S'` is YES and NO interlaced. So:

```
>>> 'NYOE S'[1::2]
'YES'
>>> 'NYOE S'[0::2]
'NO '
>>>
```

Now `s=iter(input())` is in this case roughly equivalent to `s=input()`.

`c in s for c in 'hello'` looks if the four letters h,e,l,l,o are in `s` :

```
>>> s = 'ahhellllloou' ; [c in s for c in 'hello']
[True, True, True, True, True]
>>> s = 'bye' ; [c in s for c in 'hello']
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

And finally, the `all(c in s for c in 'hello')` returns True if all letters are present, which happens to be interpreted as a 1 in a slice notation (the ::).

So putting all this together, you'll see that this does not completely fulfils the 58A question and test-cases:

```
>>> s = 'ahhellllloou' ; print('NYOE S'[all(c in s for c in 'hello')::2])
YES
>>> s = 'hlelo' ; print('NYOE S'[all(c in s for c in 'hello')::2])
YES
```

[edit] Let's finish with the role of `iter`: it consumes letters of 'hello' in the input str, in this order:

```
>>> s = iter('hlelo')
>>> 'h' in s
True
# list(s) would print ['e', 'l', 'l', 'o']  ... but would also empty the iter
>>> 'e' in s
True
# s now contains only ['l', 'o']: the first 'l' was consumed when looking for the 'e'
```

Comment: But 'hlelo' is returning me a 'NO'

Comment: You're right, my assumption `iter('hlelo')` is equiv to `'hlelo'` was wrong ; the `in` operation on the iter object consumes letters. For example : `s = iter('hlelo') ; 'e' in s ; list(s)`  leaves us with `['l','o']`. I'm editing the answer...

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. :)

Comment: By the way, instead of interlacing YES and NO, it'd be a lot more readable to use a list :  `['NO', 'YES'][True]` yields YES and `['NO', 'YES'][False]` yields NO.

Comment: Ahh yes.. thats better